# Why the * and not an F at position (2,1) in the intersection pattern matrix of the Contains predicate

Tags: de-9im, ogc-sfa

The `Contains` intersection pattern matrix should be: `T*****FF*` according to [[1](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa)], [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)] and [[3](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sf-st-contains)] (but strangely not [[4](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/dim9.html)]... for which the matrix is symmetrical, hence Contains==Within, which is not correct to me) which is the transpose of `Within`: `T*F**F***`.

I'm wondering why it's a `*` and not an `F` at position (row=2, col=1) (same goes for the `*` at position (1,2) in the `Within` matrix)?

[image]

Especially, I cannot figure out what can be the special case where "the boundary of a geometry A ∩ the interior of a geometry B" is actually *something else* than the empty set Ø (thus an `F`) in the case of the `Contains` predicate?

Any border case, such as this one between a line A `LINESTRING(10 10, 20 20)` and a Point B `POINT(12 12)` (-> `0F1FF0FF2`), leads to an `F`:

[image]

But if the point B is now `POINT(10 10)`, i.e. the starting point of the linestring, the `F` in the pattern matrix turns into a `0` but both the `True` results of A.contains(B) and B.within(A) turn into `False`.

Even for two same points, both the Contains and Within predicates return `True`, but that position (2,1) in the pattern matrix is always `F`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a common vision for all these intersection matrix patterns, which disturbs me a bit...

Comment: see the comments in this related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295064/can-linestring-contain-point).